# Highchart for DataTables basic example not working for me

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts, datatables

I have been using DataTables on my HTML tables for a few years. Now I want to add some charts with Highcharts.

I am trying to add the basic Pie chart example seen here, https://datatables.net/examples/api/highcharts.html

I have some modifications to my datatables such as hiding the default search box and adding a custom search box and exclude box, and striping the columns with alternate light and darker colors.

My web server is Apache 2.4 running on Red Hat 9

My HTML web page structure looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

<HTML>
 <HEAD>
  <META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT=5000>

   <TITLE>STUFF</TITLE>
   <LINK REL="STYLESHEET" TYPE="text/css" HREF="/includes/nav.css">
   <LINK REL="STYLESHEET" TYPE="text/css" HREF="/includes/dropdownnav.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/Favicon.png">
   <BODY MARGINWIDTH=0 MARGINHEIGHT=0 TOPMARGIN=0 LEFTMARGIN=0 RIGHTMARGIN=0>
 </HEAD>

<!-- DataTables JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/DataTables-1.13.6/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


<!-- my custom JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/search.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/rdhighchart.js"></script>


<!-- DataTables CSS -->
<LINK REL="STYLESHEET" TYPE="text/css" HREF="/js/DataTables-1.13.6/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">



<!-- Other CSS  for fa-info-circle and tooltop -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<LINK REL="STYLESHEET" TYPE="text/css" HREF="/resources/tooltip.css">

<!-- Additional files to make Highcharts work-->
    <LINK REL="STYLESHEET" TYPE="text/css" HREF="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.7.0/css/select.dataTables.min.css">
    <LINK REL="STYLESHEET" TYPE="text/css" HREF="//code.highcharts.com/css/highcharts.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.7.0/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
```

My table's ID is "example".
My table has been working fine using all the js and css links above.
To try to add Highcharts, I added the links under "Additional files to make Highcharts work"

The HTML table looks like this, the div section comes from the above example from the dataTables website

```
<div id="demo-output" style="margin-bottom: 1em;" class="chart-display"></div>

<table style="table-layout:fixed; width:650px; border:0;" align=center  id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
 <tr>
   <th class="column-title" width=100>COMPLETED</th>
   <th class="column-title" width=170>PROJECT</th>
   <th class="column-title" width=130>JOBNAME</th>
   <th class="column-title" width=80>USER</th>
   <th class="column-title" width=70>JOBID</th>
   <th class="column-title" width=60>STATUS </th>
 </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>

<tr> 
  <td align=left>2023-09-12 15:47:21</td> 
  <td align=left>mydata1</td> 
  <td align=left>mydata2/td> 
  <td align=left>mydata3</td> 
  <td align=left>mydata4</td> 
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

In my custom JS section above, I have a file named rdhighchart.js that contains the Highcharts code lifted from the example above from the datatables web site

```
    // Create DataTable
const table = new DataTable('#example');

// Create chart
const chart = Highcharts.chart('demo-output', {
    chart: {
        type: 'pie',
        styledMode: true
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Staff Count Per Position'
    },
    series: [
        {
            data: chartData(table)
        }
    ]
});

// On each draw, update the data in the chart
table.on('draw', function () {
    chart.series[0].setData(chartData(table));
});

function chartData(table) {
    var counts = {};

    // Count the number of entries for each position
    table
        .column(3, { search: 'applied' })
        .data()
        .each(function (val) {
            if (counts[val]) {
                counts[val] += 1;
            }
            else {
                counts[val] = 1;
            }
        });

    return Object.entries(counts).map((e) => ({
        name: e[0],
        y: e[1]
    }));
}
```

According to the example, I have the right javascript, the right HTML and CSS.
I am loading all the external js and css files required.

My table shows up as it always has, paginated and search box, but no pie chart.

So I decided to just make a blank html file and copy and paste the all the components from the example at https://datatables.net/examples/api/highcharts.html
This new page doesnt even show the table "DataTable-ized", no pagination, no search box and no chart.

If my both attempts, Chrome developers tools shows,

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of  rdhighchart.js:32
undefined (reading 'each')
   at chartData (rdhighchart.js:32:9)
   at rdhighchart.js:15
 chartData    @ rdhighchart.js:32
 (anonymous) @ rdhighchart.js:15
```

Line 32 is .each(function (val) {.

Line 15 is             data: chartData(table)

I do not know javascript, so I don't understand what's happening here.

There's another post about this example here, https://techsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-integrate-datatable-with-highcharts, and the code looks to be the same.

Any help or pointing in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Hi @Roger McCarrick, The problem is probably related to incorrect column count - you have six `th` tags, but only five `td`. Please check the corrected example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/46z035u8/

Comment: Thanks, here was that and I had another JS causing 2 initializations of the table